# How to overload UDFs in Spark2 using Spark Session

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to achieve method overloading UDFs in Spark2 using Spark Session.

```scala
scala> spark.udf.register("func",(a:String)=>a.length)   

scala> spark.udf.register("func",(a:Int)=>a*1000)
```

Following is my Hive table named 'orc'  and its description

```scala
scala> spark.sql("desc orc").collect.foreach(println)
[id,int,null]
[name,string,null]
[time_stamp,timestamp,null]
```

There are two records in my table

```scala
scala> spark.sql("select * from orc").collect.foreach(println)
[1,Pratap Chandra Dhan,null]
[2,Dyuti Ranjan Nayak,2016-01-01 00:00:00.0]
```

When I query using spark session, the second function takes effect, preventing method overloading

```scala
scala> spark.sql("select func(id),func(name) from  orc").collect.foreach(println)
[1000,null]
[2000,null]
```

Comment: What is the constraint for not having a new udf, which, by the way is very logical considering the functionality.

Comment: You are just overriding the previous signature when you are invoking register again in the shell. I assume you're just trying something new since multiplication and string length can be calculated using in-built functions in Spark. You can change you UDF completely to accommodate both Strings and Integers but it isn't advisable and might lead to weird results.

Comment: @sujit, Its a business constraint, hence we can not change the UDF.

Comment: @philantrovert, yes you are correct, I am trying to override trunc function of Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If really required (refer comment) you can define `func` to handle multiple types of inputs as below and register:

```
scala> val func = (a: Any) => {
     |       val i = a match {
     |       case s:String => s.length
     |       case d:Integer => d * 1000
     |       //case _ => 0
     |       }
     |       i
     |       }
func: Any => Int = <function1>

scala> spark.udf.register("func",func)
```

Comment: Please be aware that Spark doesn't like `Any`

Comment: Well, @pcdhan, the thanks shd be to me, but I am good with being marked as answer:). Though be careful of the boundary conditions.

Comment: In Spark3.0+ the registration will throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported

Answer (score -1):

*function overloading works **when the scope of functions with same name are defined having different scope*** i.e. inside a class or object.

*function overloading doesn't work when you define function inside a function. The latest definition takes over* i.e. **overriden by the latest definition**.

**for example**

I define two functions func with different types as arguments

```
scala> def func(a:String) = a.length
func: (a: String)Int

scala> def func(a: Int) = a*2
func: (a: Int)Int
```

Then I try to call the first definition

```
scala> func("sell")
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("sell")
 required: Int
       func("sell")
            ^
```

If I call the second definition (latest one) it works

```
scala> func(3)
res1: Int = 6
```

I define the first definition again i.e. the latest one is the first definition again

```
scala> def func(a:String) = a.length
func: (a: String)Int
```

Now the first function call works

```
scala> func("sell")
res2: Int = 4
```

**function overloading doesn't work in normal REPL**. You will have to enter *:paste mode*

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def func(a:String) = a.length
def func(a: Int) = a*2

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

func: (a: String)Int <and> (a: Int)Int
func: (a: String)Int <and> (a: Int)Int

scala> func("sell")
res0: Int = 4

scala> func(3)
res1: Int = 6
```